# An inequality about the areas of two triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There is point $P$ in a triangle $ABC$. $Q,R,S$ are the symmetric of $P$ with respect to the sides $AB,BC,CA$ respectively. I have to prove that the area of $ABC$ is $\geq$ than the area of $QRS$.

Any ideas?

P.S.
I noticed that if $P$ is circumcenter, the area of two triangles is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of $QRS$ is just four times the area of the [pedal triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalTriangle.html) of $P$.

By [Euler's theorem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulersTheoremForPedalTriangles/), the area of the pedal triangle just depends on the distance from the circumcenter $O$:
$$ [QRS]=\left(1-\frac{OP^2}{R^2}\right)[ABC] $$
hence the claim is trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I am still a college freshman, so I don't know such a beautiful theorem!

Comment: Besides, thank you for editing